# Can a Jewish doctor refuse to treat a wicked non-Jew?

Tags: halacha, gentiles, medicine

Ignoring any Secular law issues,

Is a Jew obligated to save the life of a wicked non Jew? Does it make a difference whether his refusal will become publicly known?

Example:

If a non-Jew who is a rasha got cancer and went to a Jewish oncologist then may the oncologist refuse to treat him? Is there an obligation for the oncologist to treat the non-Jew or an obligation to refuse him treatment? What is the halacha on this?

Comment: more specific: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/63736/170

Comment: Why my comment was deleted?

Comment: @Al Berko Mine was deleted as well. I simply asked whether the person who downvoted the question please provide a reason.

Comment: This site is extremely cautious about Jews-nonJ relations, esp not favorable ones, deleting everything that might be discriminating the laters. I'm glad you've read it before it was deleted. But that's the truth.

Comment: I asked once if this phenomenon has a name, like antigentilism? "*Defensive anti-semitism is actually pro-semitism as it protects Jews from the effects of their own hatred of gentiles.*" https://tarbaby.wordpress.com/2017/07/29/antigentilism-the-longest-hate/

Comment: This can't be Gemmarah, doesn't sound like one. Torah does not say much about antiG. It's all interpretations and Rabbinical speculations.

Comment: @Al Berko I think I might have read it many years back but maybe I don't recall correctly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89539/discussion-between-natanav-and-al-berko).

Comment: Can he treat a wicked *Jew*?